# H2 Update case when query not working

Tags: sql, database, h2

Hi I am trying to run the following H2 query via JDBC and it is giving me error saying `r.b1` not found.

```
Update t1 r SET o1 =
CASE WHEN r.b1<= r1.b1 THEN r1.b1
   ELSE r.b1
END
FROM t1 r JOIN t1 r1 
ON ( r1.c1=r.c1 and r1.c2 =r.c2 and r1.ranking = r.ranking-1)
```

Please guide. I am new to H2. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use h2 CASEWHEN function    : 
http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#casewhen_function